# Can I visit the UK with Italian stay permit?

Tags: uk

My wife and kids are Italian citizens.  Can I visit the UK with my stay permit without a visa?

Comment: No. All other things being equal, your permit will *help* getting a visa, but it won't replace it. That works only in the Schengen area, which the UK did not join.

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: @o.m. if the card is an article 10 card, which it might well be, then that's the wrong duplicate and the answer to the question is "maybe" rather than "no."

Comment: Please upload a copy of your stay permit.

Answer (score 0):

No, UK is not in the Schengen area, so you need a visa to enter UK (unless you are from a country which is in the list of countries which don't need a visa to enter UK, check it on https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y)

Comment: What if the card is an article ten card and the traveler is accompanying or joining his wife?

Comment: he didn't say that otherwise there should be no doubts...